# How to build a google chrome extension that checks meta or title tag?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to build a chrome extension that automatically opens google.com as it sees the title tag or the meta tag contains the word videos?

I am new to building chrome extensions I tried it this way.

background.js

```
    var title = document.title;
     var metatags = document.getElementByTagName("META");
     if(title.search('videos') > 0){
    window.open('https://www.google.com');
    }
     else{
        for(i = 0;i<metatags.length;i++){
            var meta_content = metatags[i].content;
            if(meta_content.search('videos')>0){
                window.open('https://www.google.com');
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

manifest.json

`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "videos",
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"An extension that goes to google chrome if it comes across the word videos in head or meta tag",
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the code.